# How to retrieve an entity with related entities in .net core with raw SQL queries?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following models, `Visit.cs` and `Prescription.cs`. I want to get all rows of visit with each instance containing the related prescriptions. I use the following EF Core query but the `medicines` field is always empty. I'm using postgresql as the database. What should I do?

Visit.cs:

```
public class Visit
{
    public int patient_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime visit_date { get; set; }
    public int doctor_id { get; set; }
    public int prescription_id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Prescription> prescriptions { get; set; }
}
```

Prescription.cs:

```
public class Prescription
{
    public int prescription_id { get; set; }
    public string medicine { get; set; }
    public Visit Visit { get; set; }
}
```

and my query:

```
var visits = dbContext.Visits
                      .FromSqlRaw("select * from visit natural join prescription")
                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) for `.FromSqlRaw` mentions this in the [limitations section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations)

They do give an example of how to [include related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#including-related-data) however by composing over the raw query:

```
var visits = dbContext.Visits
  .FromSqlRaw("select * from visit")
  .Include(v=>v.prescriptions)
  .ToList();
```

I would also strongly recommend that you do NOT use * in any query.  List the columns that you need returned.  Using * will cause the database to return all the columns, even ones that you don't want.  Forcing the database to return the unused columns can cause it to not use indexes it might otherwise be able to use, or cause the database to do row seeks that it really shouldn't need to do.  A good example would be a DBA adding columns for things like CreateDate, UpdateDate, CreateUser, UpdateUser and/or RowVersion to help with change tracking or replication.

Comment: I think also that the table name is Visits and not Visit.

Comment: @ilyes He called it `visit` in his query, so that is what I used.

Comment: yes I saw that but here "dbContext.Visits" we see that the name of the table is Visits.

Comment: @ilyes The name of the DbSet and the table do not have to be the same.

Comment: @ilyes Actually this is one of the more common ways that DbSet and table names differ.  Many DBAs prefer the singular version of table names because it makes SQL appear more natural, while most application developers prefer a plural name for tables because they think of it as a collection of the singular.  For example: `SELECT id FROM products WHERE products.id=1`  the `products.id=1` seems wrong because we are talking about a singular product id there (the one for each row).  Hence the disconnect between DBA and app devs.

Comment: And also, do not use ToList(). It causes slower performance. Use AsQueryable() instead. Loaded 80,000 records -> AsQueryable() takes 0.34ms and ToList() takes 2348.13ms.

Comment: @Asherguru You are likely including the actual query time in your calculations there which is misleading.  Without the .ToList, .ToArray, or some other method which starts iterating the result, the query doesn't get executed yet.  But yes, technically .AsQueryable does run faster, but not to the extent you've shown, and it also allows downlevel code to further manipulate the query before it gets executed -- this can be bad if the manipulation can come from unsanitized user input.